# Load dbg symbol file into WinDbg

Tags: windbg, debug-symbols

I have a MAP file for a DLL which I'm trying to debug. I converted this to a DBG file with the Map2Dbg-tool and put it into the symbol path.

Issuing a *.reload /f mydll.dll* doesn't work though, a symbol load error occurs.

I then tried to diagnose it with *!sym noisy* and it tells me that Windbg looks into the correct symbol path, but only for a PDB file (*mydll.pdb*).

Is there a way to force Windbg to find my DBG file?

**Edit:**

Here are some further infos:

Symbol search path in Windbg:

```
> .sympath
e:\code-factory\symbols;cache*;SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

dbg-file is in that directory:

```
e:\code-factory\symbols> dir /b
cdmod.dbg
cdmod.map
...
```

.reload output:

```
> .reload /f cdmod.dll

DBGHELP: e:\code-factory\symbols\cdmod.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: e:\code-factory\symbols\dll\cdmod.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: e:\code-factory\symbols\symbols\dll\cdmod.pdb - file not found
SYMSRV:  D:\Portable\Debugging Tools for Windows\x86\sym\cdmod.pdb\BD09115E93474ABCB6152149A23F95372\cdmod.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  Get File Path: /download/symbols/cdmod.pdb/BD09115E93474ABCB6152149A23F95372/cdmod.pdb


************* Symbol Loading Error Summary **************
Module name            Error
cdmod                    PDB not found : e:\code-factory\symbols\symbols\dll\cdmod.pdb
                Unable to locate the .pdb file in this location

                       PDB not found : cache*
                Unable to locate the .pdb file in this location

                       The system cannot find the file specified : SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
                The SYMSRV client failed to find a file in the UNC store, or there
                is an invalid UNC store (an invalid path or the pingme.txt file is
                not present in the root directory), or the file is present in the
                symbol server exclusion list.
```

Thanks

Comment: I see Windbg looking for .dbg files when I try `.reload`.  Could you post the output of your `.reload` command?

Answer (score 5):

`Drag and Drop` the *.dbg file to the `folder where exe exists`
if `lm output` of the module indivates `imagexxxxxxx` instead of the module name
change the name of dbg file to match it like `imagexxxxx.dbg`
do `.reload /f` and windbg should load your dbg file with `cv code symbols`

pre directory contents

```
    :\>dir /b
    msgbox.exe
    msgbox.map  < created via ida produce map
```

convert map to dbg

```
    :\>map2dbg msgbox.exe  lucian wischik utility
    Converted 7 symbols.
```

post directory contents

```
    :\>dir /b
    msgbox.dbg
    msgbox.exe
    msgbox.map
```

load exe in windbg

```
    :\>windbg msgbox.exe    
0:000> lm 
start    end        module name
00400000 00404000   image00400000   (deferred) 

0:000> .reload /f
Reloading current modules
ERROR:Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for image00400000 

0:000> lm e
start    end        module name
00400000 00404000   image00400000   (no symbols)

$ rename the msgbox.dbg to image00400000.dbg
```

renaming the dbg file

```
    :\>ren msgbox.dbg image00400000.dbg        
    :\>dir /b
    image00400000.dbg
    msgbox.exe
    msgbox.map
```

symbol file with cv code symbol info loaded into windbg

```
0:000> .reload /f
Reloading current modules
0:000> lm e
start    end        module name
0:000> lm m i*
start    end        module name
00400000 00404000   image00400000   (codeview symbols)     
C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\nosym\image00400000.dbg

0:000> x image00400000!*
00401000 image00400000!start = <no type information>
0040101a image00400000!MessageBoxA = <no type information>
00401020 image00400000!ExitProcess = <no type information>
00403000 image00400000!Caption = <no type information>
00403019 image00400000!Text = <no type information>

0:000> da image00400000!Caption
00403000  "Iczelion's tutorial no.2"
```